# How to make a function that can be edited and saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In this situation when I add a todo item to the list and try to edit the added todo, it will only add one new letter and typing the next letter it will only replace the latest letter all the time. For instance, the word is hello, no matter how many letters you type there will be only one letter added (for instance `hellop`, `hellow`, `hellol`, `hellop`). Check the `console.log` to understand the problem.

[link to snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/todo-react-typescript)

```js
  const addTodo: AddTodo = newTodo => {
    newTodo.trim() !== "" && setTodos([...todos, { text: newTodo, complete: false, edit: false }]);
  }
    
  
  const getEditText: GetEditText = getEditedTodo => {
    console.log('getEditText ' + getEditedTodo);
  }

  const saveEditedTodo: SaveEditedTodo = currentTodo => {
    console.log('saveEditedTodo ' + JSON.stringify(currentTodo.text));
  }
  
   return (
    <div>
        <input type="input" onChange={(e) => getEditText(e.target.value)} value={todo.text} />
        <span onClick={() => saveEditedTodo(todo)}>Save</span></div> :

    <li>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the new value to variable todo.next

You need to update the variable to which value is binded for input field. So please try to create a fiddler for these kind of questions